# How can logstash be executed? (error occured)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logstash

How can logstash be executed? (error occured)

run logstash on AWS Linux.
but error occurred while executing.

- my Linux(Ubuntu Version: 20.04)
- elasticsearch installed.(execute successfully)
- kibana installed.(execute successfully)
- logstash installed. (execute error occured)

`my .conf file code`

```
input {
    jdbc {
        clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://AWSLINK:3306/schema_name?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from schema_name"
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => 52.188.20.167:9200"
        index => "AWS_DB_0514"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

I execute logstash in linux(command)

```
./logstash -f test.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/
```

**I execute above code but error occured.(attempt)**

```
Sending Logstash logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2021-05-14T08:37:16,025][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Log4j configuration path used is: /etc/logstash/log4j2.properties
[2021-05-14T08:37:16,039][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.12.0", "jruby.version"=>"jruby 9.2.13.0 (2.5.7) 2020-08-03 9a89c94bcc OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.10+9 on 11.0.10+9 +indy +jit [linux-x86_64]"}
[2021-05-14T08:37:16,466][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2021-05-14T08:37:17,524][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2021-05-14T08:37:18,048][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of [0-9], [ \\t\\r\\n], \"#\", \"}\" at line 16, column 24 (byte 608) after output {\n    elasticsearch {\n        hosts => 52.188", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:32:in `compile_imperative'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:184:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:69:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:47:in `initialize'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:52:in `execute'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:389:in `block in converge_state'"]}
[2021-05-14T08:37:18,165][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
[2021-05-14T08:37:18,177][FATAL][org.logstash.Logstash    ] Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (SystemExit) exit
org.jruby.exceptions.SystemExit: (SystemExit) exit
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:747) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at org.jruby.RubyKernel.exit(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:710) ~[jruby-complete-9.2.13.0.jar:?]
        at usr.share.logstash.lib.bootstrap.environment.<main>(/usr/share/logstash/lib/bootstrap/environment.rb:89) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: Check  your pipeline config

Comment: @Johnny thx:) this is problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error on line 16.

`incorrect code`

```
hosts => 52.188.20.167:9200"
```

`correct code`

```
hosts => "52.188.20.167:9200"
```